# HM-10 serial communication from Windows

Tags: windows, arduino, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

The low-cost BlueTooth 4.0 module that connects over UART to Arduino (the default device name is MLT-BT05), usually branded as something like "BLE 4.0 Bluetooth HM-10 CC2540 CC2541 Serial Wireless Module Arduino Android IOS" is a BLE (BlueTooth Low Energy Device).

On the side of the Arduino, it works like a usual Bluetooth 2.0 serial modem - connects to Rx,Tx pins to transmit data.

However, the BLE does not support the traditional RFCOMM serial protocol that creates "virtual serial port" service when the BT device is connected on Windows.

Yet, on a PC with BT4.0 support, the device can be paired (with PIN 123456 instead of traditional 1234), and its services can be explored with the BlueTooth LE Lab software.

That is, the Windows is clearly capable to talk to this device, explore its services, etc.

Now, when using Android phone, I can nicely connect to Arduino using this module with Arduino Bluetooth Control (HM-10 Module) Android app.
It works as expected - like a usual serial terminal. Characters typed on the terminal are transmitted to Arduino's UART Rx pin, and characters sent from Arduino's UART Tx pin are transmitted and shown in the Android app. (In fact I am using SoftwareSerial to utilize different pins, but it does not matter).

Now my question is - can this kind of serial connection be done from Windows PC?

I have only found a page discussing talking to Reflowduino claiming that the same procedure works for HM-10: https://github.com/botletics/Reflowduino/wiki/Windows-10-BLE

Unfortunately, it does not. I can find the device in the BT LE Lab on the Windows machine, see the characteristics and services, but none of them resembles that "Unknown Characteristic" that would have "Writing" edit line for sending data. Still, that would only allow sending, but not receiving.

If this device (HM-10) is meant for serial communication, and clearly it works on Android (and most likely on iPhone) I wonder why nobody bothered to implement this functionality for Windows?

The issue is that the old good BlueTooth 2.0 serial modem (such as HC-05) is not compatible with iPhones, so if the BLE would talk to Windows, we could use it as a generic replacement that is compatible with all the platforms - for the applications when we want to control an embedded device over the BT.

Just a side comment, talking to the HM10 BTLE device from Linux (same PC) works smoothly:

```
# hcitool dev
Devices:
    hci0    <my BT address>
# hcitool lescan
LE Scan ...
50:F1:4A:BC:14:4C HM10-11
# gatttool -b 50:F1:4A:BC:14:4C -I
[50:F1:4A:BC:14:4C][LE]> connect
Attempting to connect to 50:F1:4A:BC:14:4C
Connection successful
[50:F1:4A:BC:14:4C][LE]> primary
attr handle: 0x0001, end grp handle: 0x000b uuid: 00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
attr handle: 0x000c, end grp handle: 0x000f uuid: 00001801-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
attr handle: 0x0010, end grp handle: 0x0022 uuid: 0000180a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
attr handle: 0x0023, end grp handle: 0xffff uuid: 0000ffe0-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[50:F1:4A:BC:14:4C][LE]> char-desc
...many others...
handle: 0x0025, uuid: 0000ffe1-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
...some more...
```

then sending a character 'a' from Arduino results in the following notification appearing instantly:

```
Notification handle = 0x0025 value: 61
```

when fast-typing several characters are combined in the same notification:

```
Notification handle = 0x0025 value: 72 65 77
```

sending chars to Arduino over BT is also straight-forward, the following sends char 'b':

```
[50:F1:4A:BC:14:4C][LE]> char-write-req 0x0025 62
```

So writing a simple terminal program for Linux using the underlying gatttool should be easy, I will post it here soon. It would be nice, if Windows PowerShell would ever run this too...(?)

Another note: I did not even have to pair the device from Linux (maybe because default security of gatttool is set to low).

Adding one more very useful resource: http://www.martyncurrey.com/hm-10-bluetooth-4ble-modules/

Comment: TL;DR. Sorry, what exactly is the question here?

Comment: Hi, thanks. A rather simple one: is there a way to talk to this thing from Windows? https://www.ebay.com/itm/BLE-4-0-Bluetooth-HM-10-CC2540-CC2541-Serial-Wireless-Module-Arduino-Android-IOS/283333952014

Comment: What we need here is a virtual com port on windows for BLE devices.

Comment: That would be nice. For the time being, I would be happy also for an app that would support this protocol. If in addition to raw, telnet, rlogin, ssh, and serial in Putty (or any other terminal program) there would also be the BLE option.

Comment: I don't own any HM-10 device but, reading the page you mentioned https://github.com/botletics/Reflowduino/wiki/Windows-10-BLE , I can tell this is the proper way to act under Windows 10.
There is no such thing as a "Virtual COM Port" for any BLE device: you actually 'talk' to them through 'service' and 'characteristic'. And in your case, the closest thing to a 'serial port' is the combination of a 'custom service' (not displayed) and 'custom characteristic' {0000FExx-...} (documentation of HM-10 will probably explain what they all are intended for...). /tbc/

Comment: So, to mimic a 'serial communication', you'd have to:
1- connect to the device and 'connect' to the proper 'custom service'
2- most probably, 'connect' to the proper Characteristic and 'subscribe' to get later Notification/Indication 
3- then 'write' to the characteristic (similar to your TX action)
4- wait and catch 'notification/indication' of that Characteristic (similar to your RX action).
You have an asynchronous read/write mechanism! :)

Comment: For the time being, I will add a link to this interesting thread related: https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/issues/1089

Answer (score 0):

Sadly I have the same problem with my knockoff HM-10 and while there is no way to connect this to windows with serial there is a virtual comm port for Bluetooth devices in windows or at least Windows 10 as far as I know, if you go into Bluetooth settings pair your device then go to the top right and click more Bluetooth options then click the COM ports tab then click outgoing and select your device from the dropdown menu then select add your device will be able to work with windows over serial as if it were connected over usb.

Comment: You must be talking about a different BT module. This kind - BTLE - leaves the tab with COM ports empty after it was paired. The way you described works with HC-05, and similar BT modules that have earlier version of BT and not BTLE.

Answer (score 0):

Windows  bluetooth standard conection wont work, because the bluetooth devices uses ble mode that doesnt require pairing. Use this which recieves through ble mode and redirects to a com port. https://github.com/Jakeler/ble-serial